# Let's burninate [substring] and/or [substrings]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, burninate-request

It is obvious that [substring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/substring) and [substrings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/substrings) should be synonymized, for they have nearly identical meanings. However, I think neither of them would be useful on this site, and thus can be burninated. Here are my reasons:

1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous? **No.**
2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site? **Yes.**
3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post? **No.**
4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts? **Absolutely not. "Substring" could mean different things in the context of Java, regular expression, JavaScript (which has a method named [`substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)), and other places.**

Comment: Not really agree with your first and last point evn 3rd is contestabmle, but definitively this tag isn't worth, maybe in something more general like 'string-processing' or whatever. Quite a lot of questions seems to come from people that didn't do they homework before posting.

Comment: Do you want to burn the tags or create a synonym? Pick one.

Comment: @gunr2171 I think these two tags **could** be burninated, and at least **should** be synonymized, if too many people disagree to burninate them.

Comment: How does a substring mean something different in C# and Java?

Comment: @rene This is my fault. I've edited to clarify.

Comment: A substring generally refers to a portion of a string, no?

Comment: I see you removed C# now but I still fail to see what the differences of substring are in those context remaining? Is one of them about a part of string in a musical instrument where others are about characters found in the middle of a bunch or characters?

Comment: Maybe you should ask Trogdor.

Answer (score 16):

### Let's not.

> 1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied?

Yes. It tells you very clearly that the question is going to be about manipulating substrings.

> 1b. Is it unambiguous?

Well, no. But this is a stupid criterion. I've made this argument before, and a bunch of Meta regulars profoundly disagree with me, so I'll try to avoid belaboring it. But consider that the vast majority of tags—nay concepts in the world—are ambiguous. Do you think we should have a [string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/string) or [char](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/char) tag? What about a [localization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/localization) tag? [vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vector)? [assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/assembly)? [file-io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file-io)? All of these tags are equally as ambiguous as [substring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/substring). Strict adherence to this "rule" would require that we burninate all of them. I argue that we should instead use common sense and follow a better rule, something along the lines of, "Is this tag *useful* for categorizing questions?"

> 2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

Yes? Yes. Agreed.

> 3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

Debatable, for the same reasons as #1b. You offer no explanation in your proposal as to why the fact that the question is about manipulating substrings is not "meaningful".

> 4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

Depends on how deep you go down the rat hole. You have fallen into said hole. Yes, every language and/or library probably has a different way of working with substrings, and even strings in general. That doesn't make those tags useless, it just explains why, in most cases, you will *also* want to include a language/library tag on your question.

To pre-empt all of the "but if it can't be used alone, that means it's a meta tag" comments: no, I didn't say it can't be used alone. If you're asking a general, algorithm-style question about substrings, then you can certainly use the [substring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/substring) tag alone. However, if you want an answer that takes into account specific usage patterns in a particular language or library, you should use that tag.

---

That's not to say that this is a *perfect* tag, but I don't think the argument is anywhere *near* strong enough for its burnination.

However, I do *strongly* support merging [substrings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/substrings) into [substring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/substring) and creating a synonym.