# Useless [use] now used less

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

*This tag has been burninated. Please do not recreate it. If you need advice on which tag to use, see the answer below. If you see this tag reappearing, it may need to be blacklisted.*

---

Current description

> USE is a keyword or statement used in several technologies. When using this tag, always pair it with another tag like SQL or Perl. Don't use this tag for expressing the "use" of something.

Tagged questions: 304.

It is impossible to [use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/use) this as the only tag on a question and still understand what the question is about and what technology is being used. This is a meta tag and should be removed.

The use keyword does not mean the same thing between different languages.

- In SQL it selects which database should be used for any following queries
- In Elixir it executes a `__using__` macro defined in the specified module
- In Perl it imports some semantics into the current package (this may have a similar use case to the Elixir usage)
- In PHP it is used to:

  - namespace your functions instead of using the full namespace
  - include a Trait within a class
  - inherit variables from the parent scope inside a closure
- In FoxPro without arguments closes, with proper arguments it opens: a table and its associated index files, a SQL view, or any project resources.

Comment: But if we burninate it how would you tag [Use Case Diagram](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40865676/should-i-use-include-to-present-process-flow-in-use-case-diagram)?

Comment: Might want to read this: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-burninating-tags and specifically [the 4 criteria](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191) for a burnination request.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to express with your comment. But I think it fails the first criteria there. It is ambiguous. From the link on that page [commonly referred to as "meta tags"](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) "**If the tag can't work as the only tag on a question, it's probably a meta-tag**". This tag cannot work on its own.

Comment: It has to meet more than one of the criteria. [A tag being "ambiguous" is not a sufficient reason for burnination](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339244/lets-burninate-substring-and-or-substrings/339251#339251). I'm not saying that I'm against this burnination request, but I don't think you've presented sufficient evidence to make the case yet. It concerns me that this actually a keyword or special identifier in programming-related technologies. It may be that we need to figure out a way to *disambiguate* it instead.

Comment: @JustinWood: My point is that a burnination should address all 4 points *and* present a strategy for dealing with the affected questions. Even if we agree to remove the tag, it's not just about removing it: it's also about checking if the affected questions should be retagged with more specific tags. For example, maybe it often comes paired with "socks" and a "use-socks" tag should be created because in this language "use xxx socks" is a pattern that's worth tagging.

Comment: @CodyGray Yes. There is [SVG use element](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#UseElement), [Perl use function](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html), [PHP use statement](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php), etc... And they are all being used in the questions of the tag.

Comment: @CodyGray Dunno you, but Shog said that ["a good tag should meet all 4 criteria"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#comment896615_239191) This one, according you, fails at least one. I say it fails at least three: doesn't add anything meaningful to the post, isn't on topic on the site, doesn't mean the same in all context.

Comment: The wiki tag description states it is supposed to be "paired" with another tag. That implies that the "correct" tags would be ones which include the additional information: For example: [sql-use], [elixir-use], [perl-use], [php-use], [foxpro-use], [svg-use], [cobol-use], etc. I'm not arguing for the [use] of any of these tags. Each one would need to be considered on its own merits.

Comment: Stats at the start of featuring: Q: +67/-4. No answers.

Comment: **Moderator Note** Please don't start burninating the tag before the community has a chance to agree or disagree.

Comment: Will we [use] Trogdor for this burnination (if approved)?

Comment: The problem with the 'meta tag' thing, is you'd assume the ambiguous uses would have enough in common that there was at least some concept of what the tag meant. Ie a concept about 'case/switch' might exist thats common to multiple languages but "use" is a bit like "the". its a *very* vague verb.

Comment: @Shayne the litmus test for meta tags is "can this be the only tag on the question?" The use tag fails this test. Or do you have other criteria to identify meta tags?

Comment: Stats at the end of featuring: Q: +116/-5. A (saying yes) +42/-1. The community has voted in favour of the burnination.

Answer (score 49):

I agree with this burnination request. Answering  [the 4 questions for burnination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191):

1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

   No. It does not describe the contents of the question to which it is applied, as we do not know about what "use" the OP is talking about. If the use tag is the only one, then we would have no idea about the question. The tag is also ambiguous, from a [comment by Makyen](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342178/should-we-burninate-the-use-tag#comment437715_342178):

   > The wiki tag description states it is supposed to be "paired" with another tag. That implies that the "correct" tags would be ones which include the additional information: For example: [sql-use], [elixir-use], [perl-use], [php-use], [foxpro-use], [svg-use], [cobol-use], etc. I'm not arguing for the [use] of any of these tags. Each one would need to be considered on its own merits.

   Pairing a tag with another implies that it's being used as a meta tag.
2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

   No. "use" is a very broad tag and most of its uses are not on-topic for the site. Some deleted questions are related to "using of code", "use of things to create code", etc, which are all either too broad, or primarily opinion based.

   Additionally related to the point about "use" being a keyword, there are many other keywords, which are not tags. Unless the keyword is used to denote an important programming concept in a given language (like lambda), it is not useful to create a separate tag for each keyword.
3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

   No. The tag is superfluous on most of the questions. As mentioned earlier, it is required for the tag to be paired with another tag, and therefore it is not useful on its own.
4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

   No. It does not have the same meaning in all common contexts. There are 3 different meanings for the word use in common context, 1. As a programming keyword, 2. to "take, hold, or deploy" and 3. "the action of using something".

I agree with [Cody's comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342178/should-we-burninate-the-use-tag#comment437126_342178) stating that 'A tag being "ambiguous" is not a sufficient reason for burnination', however this tag has a "No" answer for all the four criteria, and therefore it should be burninated.

Comment: Just a quibble on your point 3. "...and therefore it is not useful on its own" is not the question being asked. It seems that in some posts it *does* add useful information, by narrowing down which specific feature of the library/database/whatever is referred to.

Comment: @SteveBennett, I meant to say, "... and does not add any meaningful information to the post on its own". I was looking at the general cases, where it did seem redundant. Like PHP (which was the top related tag with some 100 posts tagged), where it had to go with [namespaces], or with [svg] (the second top related tag), where there were no posts that were tagged just [use] and not [svg], but related to [svg]. I guess in a few cases, it might help to narrow down, but in most of the cases, it wasn't. Those few cases need to be found out, and documented in the other community wiki answer.

Comment: One of them which I immediately found was the [use] [case] diagrams, where it added information, and was quite clear that the user was referring to UML use case diagrams.

Answer (score 8):

[use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/use) has been *burninated*.

[image: trogdor]

Thanks to everyone who participated.

## Observations/Retag Guidance:

- Use [use-case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/use-case) when the question is about Use Case diagrams.
- Drop the tag whenever it is also being used with [namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/namespaces) and [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php). If the [namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/namespaces) isn't present, and it is required, then add the [namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/namespaces) tag.  [Relevant conversation in the PHP chat room.](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/43981067#43981067)
- Many of the [perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl) questions are about using modules, and can be retagged [perl-module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl-module)

## Progress:

The [use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/use) tag is in the process of being burninated. You can help out by reviewing the questions with this tag, and...

- **editing** questions (to improve the question *and* remove the tag),
- **flagging/closing** questions that are duplicates/off-topic/unclear/too broad/opinion-based,
- filtering on this tag in the [Close Vote Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/?filter-tags=use),
- **voting** on questions with this tag,
- voting to **delete** the questions with this tag (after they have been closed, and only if the entire Q&A contains nothing of value). However, keep in mind that at the end of the burnination process all closed questions containing this tag will be deleted automatically. Thus, there's rarely a need to vote to delete these questions.

Here are some quick links to get you started:

- [Open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Buse%5D+closed%3Ano)
- [Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Buse%5D+closed%3Ayes)
- [Unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Buse%5D+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano)
- [No Accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Buse%5D+hasaccepted%3A0+closed%3Ano)

## [Track the progress of burnination](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180287/burnination-progress-for-the-use-tag)

[image]

## Remember that burnination is a *clean-up* effort!

#### Salvage whatever possible by editing and re-tagging.

We don't want to destroy value, so salvaging a post should be your first priority. If a question can be saved, please edit it. Your edit should improve *all* problems with the question *and* remove the [use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/use) tag, possibly replacing it with another tag, as described above in "Observations/Retag Guidance".

#### Unsalvageable questions should just be flagged/closed. They don't need to be retagged.

If the question is not appropriate for this site, then don't worry about removing the [use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/use) tag—just flag/close the question it is attached to.

At the end of the burnination process, all questions that still remain with the [use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/use) tag should have been closed. These will be mass-deleted, which will remove the tag from the system automatically, with minimal disruption.

#### Ask for help if you need it.

If you have any questions about specific questions you come across, or the process in general, please feel free to leave a comment on this post. You can also drop into the [SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) for real-time advice and discussion.