# This tag in[var]iably needs to be burninated

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

I came across the [var](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/var) tag on a question not too long ago. The tag wiki is not very specific, with the description stating only that

> var is a keyword in a number of programming languages.

It is impossible (as far as I can tell) to be an expert in [var](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/var). So what, you can type a three letter word with extra precision or something?

It wouldn't always mean the same thing in different contexts; the tag wiki references the keyword's usage in three separate languages, while linking to a Wikipedia page on variables. It seems that even the creator(s) of the tag wiki were unsure of its exact purpose, and it has no synonyms to related tags like [variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/variables) or language-specific uses.

It doesn't clearly explain what the question is about; it's almost always used in combination with other tags, like [swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift)[var](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/var) or [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript)[var](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/var)[let](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/let).

Comment: I love it - type a three letter word with extra precision :)

Comment: "It is impossible (as far as I can tell) to be an expert".  Just look at the top-users page for the tag.  You'll see the experts, Guffa has 21 answers, Jon Skeet has 17, several have multiple answers, 133 users have favorited it.  Nothing wrong with that tag, don't mess with it please.

Comment: Stand-alone the tag is ambiguous, but if combined with a programming language tag, it is not.

Comment: @HansPassant But are they really an expert in [tag:var], or is that just from coming across it accidentally and happening to answer a lot of questions about a related language that have the tag?

Comment: @Lundin Doesn't that sound like a meta-tag to you? In the posts where [tag:var] is somewhat useful, all you need to know about the tag is summarized by the inclusion of "var" in the title somewhere.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/374213/4832499 is almost an answer if you just replace "use" with "var".

Comment: @PasserBy: I think we could make a ruling for all keywords, really. We don't need a tag for each and every keyword of each and every language in existence...

Comment: @PasserBy No, a meta tag is something like "homework", "bug", "problem" describing why a question was posted rather than what it contains.

Comment: `var burninateRequest = true;`

Comment: @Lundin "If the tag can’t work as the only tag on a question, it’s probably a meta-tag." – https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms *probably* a meta-tag. Not being able to stand alone is a sign to be suspicious, but isn't in itself sufficient to make something a meta-tag. [homework] is a meta-tag because it doesn't describe the contents of the question, not because it can't stand alone.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery well, what part part of the content of the question [var] describes?

Comment: @Braiam That they're probably asking about the behavior of the `var` keyword? I'm not saying it's a *good* tag, just that it isn't a meta tag.

Comment: Questions can arise on variables but it will be more specific if the user tags it with the particular language tag. This tag is of no use

Comment: @ThumChoonTat `if (burninateRequest) Tags["var"].requestBurnination().then(burninateTag);`

Comment: This seems slightly less sisyphean than going after [tag:int], but still pointless.

Comment: @Shog9 Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 7):

The problem here is that [variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/variables) is absolutely on topic, while [var](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/var) is really just a keyword in some languages (most notably [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript)). In the case of [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript), [scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scope) might be more appropriate, since `var` is used to scope in Javascript (otherwise everything is in the global scope by default). [We burninated [use] last year for the same reason.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342178/useless-use-now-used-less)

Most use cases will be covered by the more generic [syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/syntax).

Let's examine the [burnination questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191)

> Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

`var` is merely a programming keyword ([variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/variables) is the concept which is on-topic) and it's not clear its always used the same way in every language that has it.

> Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

Variables and syntax are on-topic when the context is a programming language

> Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

Not really. Syntax words by themselves aren't useful tags. Use [syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/syntax) when asking about what a term or keyword means or how to use it.

> Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

In JS, it's used to limit [scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scope). In other contexts, it seems to be merely be a variable declaration keyword. There may be yet other usages that are esoteric.

Comment: "Variables and syntax are on-topic" as long as they are in the context of software development. Variables in models/mathematical functions and syntax of human language isn't on topic for SO.

Answer (score 3):

The [var](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/var) tag is used for

- The `/var` folder in Unix
- The keyword `var`
- Variables

This is a dependent tag and it should be burninated.

The burnination criteria:

> 1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

It is ambiguous, and does not add any information.

> 2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

Not by itself.

> 3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

No.

> 4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

No.

Comment: That is not what “meta tag” means.

Comment: "dependent tag" - a tag that cannot stand on its own. "meta tag" - a dependent tag that describes meta details about the question, rather than the question.

Comment: @BhargavRao Fixed it.

Comment: Now your argument is for disambiguation and not for burnination.

Comment: @BhargavRao if the tag ends up deleted due the disambiguation, isn't that burnination?

Comment: @Braiam, a tag never ends up getting deleted due to disambiguation. At worse it can get renamed to a more descriptive name.

Comment: (An easy way to differentiate between a tag disambiguation and a tag burnination is when the answer to Q #2 is "yes")

Comment: @BhargavRao come on, you really want to draw lines in the sand. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/348598/792066 Please, be *very* careful with using "never". More often that not, it's wrong.

Comment: @BhargavRao Fixed it again

Comment: @Braiam, I agree that the difference isn't clear, which is why I've been focusing on the cases where it is quite clear that the tag needs a disambiguation and not burnination (don't want to waste productive time over nomenclature). In the ideal sense, the tag is "never" deleted. If the tag has to be deleted at the end of a disambiguation effort, then it was a burnination effort all along.

Comment: @Braiam I wrote them down https://gist.github.com/Bhargav-Rao/220b47a45354dd4a796fbc6c15203ae0. Finally found some time for it.

Answer (score 0):

If anything, this should only be disambiguated.

Every keyword I could think of in two minutes (except `with`) has a tag. For example:

- [final](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/final) has 1,408 questions
- [const](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/const) has 4,713 questions
- [auto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/auto) has 782 questions
- [static](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/static) has 13,567 questions
- [let](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/let) has 502 questions

So you would have to either argue that there's a reason the `var` keyword in particular is a problem, or that keyword tags in general shouldn't exist, and we should burninate the rest.

On the other hand, in practice [var](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/var) is full of garbage because people slap it on whenever they use the `var` keyword, or whenever they have variables (or if they're trying to do "variable auto-regression," apparently.)

I believe we can mitigate this by renaming it to [var-keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/var-keyword) and by editing the tag wiki to clarify the tag is for questions having to do with how that keyword works.

Comment: I just proposed [burninating \[let\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/384238/will-they-let-us-burninate-this-tag). [static], [final], [const] are all programming concepts as well as keywords. [auto] would be a good one to disambiguate, since I see several misuses

Comment: I am not sure if we need a tag for specific keywords. As [I mentioned earlier](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/374213/4099593), it is better to create tags for programming concepts related to the keyword, rather than the keyword itself.

Answer (score -4):

I believe that (in most programming languages) it would indicate that the question involves declaration of variables.  I could ask if using `var foo="bar"` implicitly localizes `foo` in a given language, or if there is some advatage of this over a simple `foo="bar"`.  (Funny story, I searched to make sure my example made sense, and found that this exact issue has come up [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8059526/what-does-var-do-in-javascript-why-is-it-sometimes-part-of-an-assignment).)

The fact that it's three letters long is an artifact of programmers not wanting to type out 'variable' every time they declare one.  And that's actually to our advantage here, because we can make a distinction between the keyword and the word "variable", which can therefore be a tag for a question about variables but not necessarily about their declaration.

Answer (score -9):

The keyword `var` may be used for declarations in many languages but it also has another meaning and often is used to indicate parameters that are output or passed by reference as opposed to passed by value.

As a meta tag on a question I would see it has having value. Its just the misuse by so many people who think it stands for any use of the var keyword in any language. So perhaps the tag description is unhelpful and should be more explicit and then the tag tidied?

Comment: "often is used to indicate parameters that are output or passed by reference as opposed to passed by value." what languages are those? Also, there are [tag:pass-by-reference] and [tag:pass-by-value] for those

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Yes - I wasn't planning to include a whole lecture on parameter passing mechanisms in my answer :-)