# Will they [let] us burninate this tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

Related to [the [var] burniantion proposal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/383150/this-tag-invariably-needs-to-be-burninated). I first noticed the tag thanks to [this important JavaScript question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var)

[let](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/let) (about 500 questions)

> In Lisp-like and functional languages, introduces a list of local variables, each (possibly optionally) with its initial value.

As far as I can tell, `let` is simply a variable declaration syntax, much like its cousin `var`. More importantly, only 39 are also tagged [lisp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lisp), which means the excerpt is wildly wrong (128 are JS questions). Just like [the [use] burnination](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342178/useless-use-now-used-less), this appears the be a syntax tag only, meaning that

- Most questions could be retagged [syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/syntax)
- Some JS questions could be tagged [scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scope) (this is scoping syntax in that language)

> Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

Not necessarily. I don't think that LISP, Haskell and JS use it exactly the same way

> Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

Scope and syntax are on topic

> Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

No. Take [this Lisp question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49902313/prog-vs-let-in-lisp-performance-difference). There's no "prog" tag because that's simply syntax. [syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/syntax) would be more appropriate here, and also eliminates the need for [let]

> Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

Again, no. JS is the newcomer here and it doesn't seem that JS uses it exactly the same way other languages do.

Comment: Let is used for some more purposes in additional languages too: 10 questions about let tagged C# about linq statements, 1 VB.Net questions about the same thing, 2 VBA questions about `property let`, and more.

Comment: Also 5 with Kotlin that refers to the `let{ }` extension function

Comment: Oh, look, a word that has multiple different usages across several languages. What concrete topic could it be about?

Comment: There are a number of specific issues related to the use of the `let` keyword. It's clear, unambiguous, on-topic, and adds value to the question. I see no reason to get rid of it.

Comment: The tag description would probably need to be updated- but I don't think the tag should be burned.

Comment: I see a pattern on burnination requests. "This is a good tag", "there's no issues with this tag" "this tag is correctly used", when the request provides several examples of badness, issues and misuse of the tag. If someone wants to dispute a burnination, they also have to **provide the evidence that refutes the requester analysis** put in their request. **Otherwise these answers/comments are meaningless and shouldn't be used as criteria to determine whenever or not a proposal is supported.**

Comment: @Braiam likewise I see a pattern on burnination requests: "This is a good tag that isn't causing any harm, but I would like to waste a bunch of time destroying value on the internet so lets burninate it."

Comment: @TinyGiant you forgot "and this is why [reasons]"

Comment: So long as it makes a good Meta title, eh?

Comment: @Lewis but it has to be a good pun too. Remember, [we have a critical audience](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295583/why-do-people-have-a-little-pun-with-their-retag-and-burninate-requests/295584#comment200653_295584)

Comment: If anyone, shouldn't you burnimate both `let` and `var` ? (var actually seems worse)

Comment: @Braiam Are you seriously advocating for a "guilty until proven innocent" standard?!?

Comment: @MasonWheeler that's not a fair comparison. If you are using TDD and a piece of code doesn't fulfill the test conditions anymore, wouldn't you fix it? The only difference here is that the tag never fulfilled the test conditions but our testing framework sucks.

Answer (score 12):

This tag suffers of the same problems other tags suffer: it's used as /keyword/ or a #hashtag. Tags aren't keywords nor hashtags. Tags represent specific, well-defined categories. If the tag isn't specific or well-defined it's failing that purpose. As the question already notes, the definition of the [let](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/let) isn't self-contained. It depends on the content of the question it is supposed to describe. If I have to read the question to know what it's about after reading the tags... what purpose those tags are serving?

Another flaw, is that its creation should have never happened. On the tagging help page, it emphasize that there is a burden of proof on the creator to prove that other tags doesn't cover the topic the tag would be about:

> Even if you have sufficient reputation, you should only create new tags when you feel **you can make a strong case that your question covers a new topic that nobody else has asked about before on this site.**

For most of the topics this tag could potentially cover, exist already more specific and well-defined tags already created. For the scope in language X, X already exists. The language tag doesn't mean "this question is about language X", it means "the topic of this question is about features and idiosyncrasies of language X". Those features and idiosyncrasies includes most of the basic functioning and behaviors. That's why when asking about a library, you add said library tag: it modifies/expands the features and idiosyncrasies of the language it supports.

The keyword "let" is a representation of a feature of the language, with its specific idiosyncrasies. The topic is already covered by another more specific and useful tags. It's wasting tag space and diluting the importance of the tags reducing them to mere keywords and #hashtags. For the above reasons it causes immediate and palpable harm. If we want to improve tagging, we need to treat tags as self-defined, unambiguous entities. Removing this tag, inches us towards that goal.

Comment: While I want to use tags as keywords, this certainly isn't a useful one.

Comment: If I tag a question [javascript][let] it is extremely obvious what the question is about. It is completely unambiguous. Likewise, if I tag a question [lisp][let] it is going to be completely unambiguous what I'm asking about. The fact that lisp and JavaScript are different doesn't make the [let] tag ambiguous. It just means that, like everything ever, context matters.

Comment: @TinyGiant - You should probably post an answer to give your alternative viewpoint

Comment: @TinyGiant the tag page is very clear **tags should be able to stand alone as the only tag of the question**.

Comment: @Braiam actually that is incorrect. The part you're referring to is: "If the tag can’t work as the only tag on a question, it’s probably a meta-tag. Every tag you use should be able to work, more or less, as the only tag on a question. Meta-tags, like [beginner], [subjective], and [best-practices], are not helpful by themselves – they do not communicate anything about the content of the question." Notice that it says "it’s probably a meta-tag" meaning that it could be used as an indication that the tag may be a meta-tag, but that doesn't mean that it _is_ a meta-tag. [let] is categorically not

Comment: Notice that they also used "Here are some tips to help you determine whether a tag is a meta-tag", "more or less" and other non-committal phrases to mean that it should not be interpretted as a rule, but rather as a guideline case-by-case evaluation of whether the tag is a meta-tag or not.

Comment: @TinyGiant I'm not quoting that part. When I quote something I use quotation marks. "Tags are a means of connecting experts with questions they will be able to answer by sorting questions into specific, **well-defined** categories." A tag that needs another tag isn't well defined by any possible interpretation.

Comment: @Braiam That is the only part of the tag page that talks about tags standing by themselves. If you're not referring to that section then you're just making stuff up. As for the quote about it being well-defined, come on. That's about as nonsensical as can be. A tag can be well-defined _in context_.

Comment: Agreed here. If I can't be an expert on [tag], it shouldn't exist. No one is an expert on [tag:let].

Comment: @AdamSmith According to [top users](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/let/topusers), I am.

Comment: @Braiam Does this answer really attempt to say that [[tag:JavaScript]] is "*more specific and well-defined*" than [[tag:let]]?!

Comment: @Bergi does your answer change when I change javascript for lisp? Now what if I change let for scope?

Comment: @Braiam No, the answer would not change. [[tag:let]] is more specific.

Comment: I don't get how using tags as keywords or hashtags causes "*immediate and palpable harm*". They are **not** categories, and StackOverflow will never a well-organised, hierarchical and semantic categorisation system like in the German Wikipedia. (Or if it will, then not through tags). Hashtags are tags, as the name says, and they are supposed to be used like that. We cannot cannot "*waste tag space*", it is infinite.

Answer (score 5):

This tag is not causing any harm, is unambiguous when context is taken into consideration, adds value to the question, and it accurately describes the content of the question.

If I tag a question [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript)[let](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/let) it is extremely obvious what the question is about. It is completely unambiguous. Likewise, if I tag a question [lisp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lisp)[let](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/let) it is going to be completely unambiguous what I'm asking about. The fact that lisp and JavaScript are different doesn't make the [let](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/let) tag ambiguous. It just means that, like everything ever, context matters.

I see absolutely no reason to burninate this tag, and I believe that doing so would be destroying value, and a disservice to the community and the internet at large. Removing this tag would **not** make the internet a better place.

Comment: "Tags are a means of connecting experts with questions they will be able to answer by sorting questions into **specific, well-defined categories**." A well defined category, doesn't need other tags to convey meaning. Tags should be able to stand by themselves.

Comment: @Braiam according to you. I'm perfectly OK with tags being well-defined in the context of accompanying tags. You're literally taking two words and assigning your own interpretation to them, then saying that that interpretation should be treated as a blanket rule based solely on your own say-so. I don't see anything there to suggest that it was ever intended to mean that every tag on the site should be able to exist as the only tag on a question and still make sense. That just seems like nonsense to me, and I fail to see how that interpretation is beneficial to the internet at large.

Comment: The tag may be contextually meaningful, but it seems pointless. It's a primitive operation with significantly different behaviour between languages, but even if you narrow it to a single language, there will be no "javascript let experts", and nobody looking for questions about it specifically. The question would be relevant to anybody who's interesting in the minutia of the relevant language. If anything a broader tag like `language-lawyer` would actually make more sense (more precisely identify a useful group of users/questions) than keeping `let` as a tag. Maybe we could merge it into that.

Comment: In my opinion, anything you tag `let` in JS would more accurately be tagged `scope` or `syntax`. I personally don't see the value.

Comment: It is written: The first to state his case seems right, until another comes and questions him.

Comment: @Jeremy the expert argument is not and has never been a reason to remove a tag, and there are important distinctions regarding the use of the let keyword, so if someone is asking about those distinctions then the tag definitely adds value. I don't understand this "I think this tag is ambiguous so i recommend using a tag that could literally mean anything." If let is ambiguous then language-lawyer and syntax don't have any common meaning.

Comment: Do we need a tag for every single keyword in the language, then? This is currently not a coherent place to draw the line. If we were consistent, we'd end up with more tags than can fit on questions. The tag limit exists to avoid exactly this kind of overuse; this is a textbook example of what Jeff wanted to avoid.

Comment: @Jeremy If you're asking about a specific keyword and the tag doesn't exist, then the creation of said tag would be appropriate. If there's no questions about a specific keyword, a tag for that keyword would not make sense. I think this is fairly straightforward. The same could be said for libraries and API's. We don't need a tag for a library that no one has asked a question about, nor would we need a tag for an API that no one has asked any questions about. I can't see how this could possibly be an example of what Jeff wanted to avoid, textbook or otherwise.

Comment: @Jeremy keep in mind that this tag should not be used on every single question that includes code which utilizes the `let` keyword. It should only be used on question that are asking about the `let` keyword itself.

Answer (score 5):

It is a quite specific variable declaration syntax, it would not be covered by a general tag like [scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scope).
**Do not burninate**.

> > In Lisp-like and functional languages, introduces a list of local variables, each (possibly optionally) with its initial value.
>
> As far as I can tell, `let` is simply a variable declaration syntax, much like its cousin `var`. More importantly, only 39 are also tagged `lisp`, which means the excerpt is wildly wrong (128 are JS questions)

The excerpt isn't wrong since JavaScript *is* a functional programming language, influenced by a Lisp dialect (Scheme).

> I don't think that LISP, Haskell and JS use it exactly the same way

`let` declarations in all these languages are similar, and very different from other forms of variable declarations. There is nothing wrong with having a specific tag for this syntax.

> Most questions could be retagged [syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/syntax)

They could, but [syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/syntax) is much too generic. It would be inappropriate to tag it [programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/programming), although that would be correct as well. If it gets burninated, it should be retagged to [variable-declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/variable-declaration) at least.

> Some JS questions could be tagged [scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scope) (this is scoping syntax in that language)

Better, [lexical-scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lexical-scope).

> Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

Yes it does. It unambiguously specifies *which* syntax the question is about.

Comment: `let` in JS and `let` in Lisps are wildly different. `let` in JS shares a *lot* more genes with Scala's `var` and Swift's `let`, and unlike `let` in Rust and OCaml, you can't shadow previous `let` in the same scope. It's a binding declaration mechanism, but it does *not* work like a `let ... in` (like how Lisp, Rust, and OCaml do).

Answer (score 4):

I used to outright oppose the continued existence of tags about syntax, and even now, *if* it comes down to a choice, I still prefer a sufficiently well-delimited tag about a syntax-independent concept to a tag about syntax. However, my views on that matter have softened over time, mostly for a simple consideration, which I will illustrate with an example. If questions which are essentially about `let` declarations in Haskell were reliably tagged with both [haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/haskell) and [let](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/let), entering `[haskell][let]` in the search bar would quickly lead me to questions about that specific feature, which would, in particular, be quite handy if I were looking for a preexisting question about some detail of how `let` works in Haskell for the purposes of linking to it elsewhere, or using it as a duplicate target.

Now, one might wonder whether questions about `let` in Haskell are, in fact, reliably tagged with [let](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/let). As of now, there are:

- [52 questions tagged [haskell] and [let]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/haskell+let); and
- [149 questions tagged [haskell] but not [let] which have "let" in their titles](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bhaskell%5D+-%5Blet%5D+title%3Alet) (I estimate that between a third to half of those are essentially about `let`).

That means I can't rely on [haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/haskell)-plus-[let](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/let) showing me all relevant questions about `let` I might hope to find; furthermore, changing that scenario would require permanent vigilance in making sure new questions about `let` are tagged with [let](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/let). While that dampens my enthusiasm quite a bit, I don't think a tag not being used often enough is a good reason for burninating it. In the absence of other signs the tag [is "actively causing harm"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307124/2751851), I suggest we let it be.